# Timeout error during FTP deployment in GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: reactjs, github, yaml

I am encountering a timeout error while attempting to deploy a website using FTP in a GitHub Actions workflow. The workflow is triggered on a push event to the main branch and should upload the built files to an FTP server. However, the deployment step fails with the following error message:

```
Timeout (control socket)
Error: Error: Timeout (control socket)
```

I am using the SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.0.0 action in my workflow YAML file. Here is a simplified version of the relevant section:

```
name: Deploy website on push

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # ... other steps ...
      
      - name:  Sync files
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.0.0
        with:
          server: ftp.example.com
          username: ${{ secrets.ftp_username }}
          password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
          local-dir: ./build/
          server-dir: /
```

I have verified that the FTP server credentials are correct and that the network connectivity is stable. Manually connecting to the FTP server using a different FTP client works without any issues.

How can I troubleshoot and resolve this timeout error in my GitHub Actions workflow? Are there any specific configurations or settings I should consider? Any help would be appreciated.